# Set Exit Path Dependent on Whether User Clicks Yes or No

Tags: windows, command-line, batch-file, uac

I have a batch file that requests UAC privileges. When the UAC box pops up and a user clicks the `no` button I want to display message `No administration privileges granted. Now exiting.` and then wait three seconds before exiting. Currently If a user clicks the `yes` button the UAC prompt works, but in the background on a separate window with the exit message I applied above.

I have tried to create an IF statement towards the end of the file to specify which exit takes place dependent on the yes/no press.

Essentially I want to do a quick exit of the other command prompt window if a user clicks `yes` or display the exit message for the three seconds before exiting. Any ideas?

```
  IF '%params%' EQU == 1 (
    ECHO No administration privileges granted. Now exiting.
    TIMEOUT 3 >NUL
    EXIT /B
) ELSE ( EXIT )
```

```
@ECHO OFF
REM Check for permissions
>nul 2>&1 "%SYSTEMROOT%\system32\cacls.exe" "%SYSTEMROOT%\system32\config\system"

REM Check if UAC has been granted 
IF '%errorlevel%' EQU '0' (
    GOTO Administration_Granted
) ELSE ( GOTO UAC_Prompt )

REM Request administration privileges
  :UAC_Prompt
  ECHO Requesting administration privileges.
  ECHO Set UAC = CreateObject^("Shell.Application"^) > "%temp%\getadmin.vbs"
  SET params = %*:"=""
  ECHO UAC.ShellExecute "cmd.exe", "/c %~s0 %params%", "", "runas", 1 >> "%temp%\getadmin.vbs"

  "%temp%\getadmin.vbs"
  DEL "%temp%\getadmin.vbs"
  CLS

  IF "%params%"=="1" (
    ECHO No administration privileges granted. Now exiting.
    TIMEOUT 3 >NUL
    EXIT /B
) ELSE ( EXIT )



REM Administration Granted
:Administration_Granted
ECHO Administration privileges have been granted
TIMEOUT 2 >NUL
PAUSE
```

Comment: Closing the spaces around the `=` breaks the batch file. What am I supposed to be doing with the `set a = 5`?

Answer (score 0):

I'm going to ask on a different website as my own question is being marked down for no apparent reason, comments disappear, and I get told off for using please and thank you. Just because it's not a forum doesn't mean manners should be disallowed...